# trouble getting results from rock paper scissors code (java)

Tags: java, methods

so when I run my code, it keeps saying that it is a tie because I think there is a problem in one of my methods.

Here is my whole code:

```
   String userChoice = "";
        String computerChoice = "";
        System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors.");
        System.out.println("The rules of the game are Rock breaks Scissors, "
                + "Scissors cut Paper, and Paper covers Rock. In this game, "
                + "the user will play against the computer.");
        System.out.println("The legend for this game is: R = rock, P = paper,"
                + " and S = scissors.");

        generateUserChoice();
        generateComputerChoice();
        determiningOutcome(userChoice, computerChoice);
        repeatGame(userChoice, computerChoice);

    }

    public static String generateComputerChoice() {
        String computerChoice = "";
        int computerIntChoice;

        Random generator = new Random();
        computerIntChoice = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;

        if (computerIntChoice == 1) {
            computerChoice = "R";
        } else if (computerIntChoice == 2) {
            computerChoice = "P";
        } else if (computerIntChoice == 3) {
            computerChoice = "S";
        }
        System.out.println("The computer played "  + computerChoice);
        return computerChoice;

    }

    public static String generateUserChoice() {
        String userChoice;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please Enter your choice:");
        userChoice = input.nextLine();
        userChoice = userChoice.toUpperCase();

        return userChoice;

    }

    public static void determiningOutcome(String userChoice, String computerChoice) {

        if (userChoice.equals(computerChoice)) {
            System.out.println("It is a tie!");
        } else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("R") && computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
            System.out.println("Rock beats Scissors, you win!!");
        } else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("P") && computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("R")) {
            System.out.println("Paper beats Rock, you win!!");
        } else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("S") && computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("P")) {
            System.out.println("Scissors beats Paper, you win!!");
        } else if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("R") && userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
            System.out.println("Rock beats Scissors, you lose.");
        } else if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("P") && userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("R")) {
            System.out.println("Paper beats Rock, you lose.");
        } else if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("S") && userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("P")) {
            System.out.println("Scissors beats Paper, you lose.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, invalid choice.");
        }
    }

    public static int repeatGame(String userChoice, String computerChoice) {
        int playAgain;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.println("Would you like to play again? 1 = yes and 2 = no");
        playAgain = input.nextInt();

        if (playAgain == 1) {
       System.out.println("Would you like to play again? 1 = yes and 2 = no");
            generateUserChoice();
            generateComputerChoice();
            determiningOutcome(userChoice, computerChoice);

        }else {
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing!!");
        }

    return playAgain;    
    }

    }
```

however I think the problem is in the generateComputerChoice part of my code

Thanks in advance

Comment: You print the computer choice.  What does it print?

Comment: You're not assigning the choice variables (`userChoice` and `computerChoice`); they remain empty strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `userChoice` and `computerChoice` is always been empty therefore it always a tie.

You need to assign your `userChoice` and `computerChoice`  from the return value of the methods.

like this:

```
userChoice = generateUserChoice();
computerChoice = generateComputerChoice();
```